# Ogre3d cant link boost libraries in visual studio 2010

Tags: c++, ogre, vc10

I recently tried to set up an ogre 3d v.19 project following the tutorials on their webpage.
After setting up the project i try to build it and I get the following error:

LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib'

I made sure i'm using the right ogre SDk(vc10). I also checked if the file above was on its place - and it was! It's in the folder it's supposed to but i still get the error.

Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You should gently check, that all boost libs (basically located at "OgreSDK_vc10_v1-9-0\boost\lib\"), e.g., for debug configuration:
libboost_thread-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
libboost_system-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
libboost_date_time-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
libboost_chrono-vc100-mt-gd-1_55.lib
are declared in your project config (Project->Settings->Linker->Input->Additional dependencies). Besides, you should provide correct path, where VS2010 will seek this libs, by specifying Project->Settings->Linker->General->Additional Library Directories. After all these steps, linker have all the information to detect needed libraries and to process them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you didn't link the libraries to Boost, check for these:

Configuration Properties - Linker - General - Additional Library Directories

$(OGRE_HOME)\boost\lib
$(OGRE_HOME)\lib\$(Configuration)